# How to manage dependencies with git, for a dependency managed via npm?

Tags: git, npm, dependency-management

How can I best manage a project's dependencies with git (github) urls, where that project is managed and installed with npm, participating in that ecosystem (externally, however internally that project no longer wants to rely on npm)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is a working starting point (excerpted from `package.json` for the project)

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "git clone https://github.com/project/external.git ./lib/external || git -C ./lib/external fetch --all --tags ",
    "install": "git -C ./lib/external stash && git -C ./lib/external checkout tags/v0.1.2 ",
    "postinstall": "echo 'dependencies ./lib/external' && git -C ./lib/external status && ls ./lib/external",
```

Consuming projects use npm as-usual `npm i --save the-project` etc